# reliable place to buy .io domains

Tags: recommendations, domain-registration

I'm looking around trying to find a good place to buy **.io** domains.

Suddenly, I think I'm surrounded by scammers, since .io domain providers websites, are really badly-designed and I am not feeling of confident about dealing with them.

I'm trying to deal with [nic.io](http://nic.io) guys right now.

If somebody could point me out some company, it would be appreciated. Specially because the domain costs £60. It's not that cheap to spend with someone that could just leave you waiting for some answer after the payment.

Comment: It's funny how nic.io's Secure Registration Page points to a local IP address. I would think they are a scam too.

Comment: @john-conde, care to explain the close action. I'm afraid I can't understand why this is not constructive since it clearly helped out other users interested on the same subject.

Comment: Recommendation/list questions like this are not acceptable as per the [faq] and are better left for [chat]. Since this one has good answers already and only attracts spam and "me too" answers it is better off left closed. It won't be deleted, though, so it can still serve as a good reference for future visitors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nic.io seems to be the [official registry](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/io.html) and primary registrar for registering .io domains, so if you don't want to register through them, you're SOL. There *are* other registrars that also sell .io domains, but they're still just going through nic.io.

I'm sorry if you have bad feelings about nic.io, but that's just the nature of the domain name industry. When you have a regulatory agency like ICANN/Network Solutions, the industry naturally becomes dominated by sleazy companies. You can thank cronyism for that.

Comment: sounds good Lèse thanks for your help here, I will try to proceed with them as I'm more confident after your feedback here :)

Answer (score 2):

eNom used to support both purchase of .IO and ability to transfer .IO into eNom.

Then eNom stopped services for both, but existing registrations were kept.

Now they support registering .IO but you cannot transfer .IO into eNom at this time.

Multiple conversations with different levels of "support" at eNom indicate they will not likely support transfer ever.

I would consider **eNom not reliable** for .IO domains,

Answer (score 1):

You might also try one of their [reseller registrars](http://nic.io/registrars.html). In some cases resellers sell domains cheaper than the root authority, so it is worth checking out.